# Are they using Vandermonde's Identity here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a set of $5$ men and $7$ women. Then there are $\binom 53 \binom 72$ groups consisting of $3$ men and $2$ women. What they are doing looks very much like this identity: $\binom {m + n}{k} = \sum_{j = 0}^k \binom{m}{j} \binom{n}{k - j}$ where $m, n \ge 0$ except there's summing in Vandermonde's Identity. Please, elaborate on this.

Comment: So what are you asking for? Elaboration on why Vandermonde's Identity?

Comment: @ Salmon Killer, In the example problem, there's no summing as opposed to vandermonde's Identity.  What's different?

Comment: Vandermonde's identity would be used in a problem where they say we need to choose $k$ people from a pool of five women and three men. In this one they are already explicitly saying how many men and how many women they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combinatorial interpretation of Vandermonde and its friends is that you can divide a set of size $m+n$ into a set of size $m$ and a set of size $n$. If you want to pick $k$ things from the set of size $m+n$, you can do this by picking $j$ things from the set of size $m$, and $k-j$ things from the set of size $n$. You then sum over all the possible $j$.

Your problem is describing one instance of picking $j$ from a set of size $m$ and $k-j$ from a set of size $n$, with $m=5$, $n=7$, $j=3$ and $k=5$. A problem that would use Vandermonde would be to ask for all ways of picking a set of size $5$ from the set of size $12$ of all the people, by way of counting the number with one man, two men, ... and five men.

Comment: So, Vandermonde is the generalization of the given problem?

Comment: Well, basically.

Comment: Products of binomial coefficients like $\binom {m}{k} \binom {n}{j}$ as a solution to a problem where neither term is the coefficient of the other make me seriously uncomfortable. Now that I know that the given problem is just a special case of Vandermonde's I can sleep better because Vandermonde has a proof and not just another faceless problem solved with seemingly arbitrary operations. Thanks.

Comment: Independent choice means multiplication, just as in probability.

Comment: Because $|A| \times |B| = A \cdot B$ where $A, B$ are sets?

Answer (score 1):

They are not using Vandermonde's identity.

Simply put there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select the three women and there are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select the two men.

By the rule of product there are $\binom{5}{3}\cdot\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select the whole set.

Comment: Basically they are counting 2 element lists then. If we were to think in lists, how would we know the length of the lists?

Comment: the length of the list is 5, but we know three of the elements are women and two are men.

Comment: What I meant was something along the lines of this: how many lists of length three taken from the set $\{1, 2\}$ are there?. There are $2$ ways to select the first element, another two to select the second element and there are two more for the third one. $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2.$ Except here the length of the lists is given explicitly.